# Providing reference of facebook sdk in my application

Tags: android, facebook

I am developing an application in which I have to integrate facebook. But, whenever, I give reference of facebook SDK in my application, it does not take it. The process aborts at 73%. I downloaded SDK from github and I had also installed EGit eclipse plug-in. But still, I am unable to provide reference. I am not getting what is the actual problem. Whether is there any  problem in eclipse or some other problem is there?

Comment: Do you have created the android facebook sdk as an Android library project in Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, I did but after this step I am unable to give reference of android sdk.